# How do I write this dictionary of lists to a csv file in this format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I want to write this dictionary of lists to a csv file in this format using csv:

```
Ola, elizabethy, beale/cambray,st_hildas
Evie, st_hildas,beale/cambray,elizabethn
Lorna,   beale/cambray,elizabethn,st_hildas
```

So that I can eventually write it to an excel file that appears like this:

```
Ola     elizabethy      beale/cambray    st_hildas
Evie    st_hildas       beale/cambray    elizabethn
Lorna   beale/cambray   elizabethn       st_hildas
```

This is the way it looks in python.

`students = {"Ola":["elizabethy","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],"Evie":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"],"Lorna":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Morgan":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],"Ola1":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Lorna1":["elizabethn","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],"Lorna2":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Evie1":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],"Evie3":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"]}`

Comment: What was your attempt? Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"Ola":["elizabethy","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],"Evie":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"],"Lorna":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Morgan":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],"Ola1":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Lorna1":["elizabethn","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],"Lorna2":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Evie1":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],"Evie3":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df.T.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: thank you this worked as well but gave me:"0,1,2" at the beginning

Comment: @casualcoder use  `df.T.to_csv("test.csv", header=False)` to avoid the header (0,1,2)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
students = {"Ola":["elizabethy","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],"Evie":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"],"Lorna":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Morgan":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],"Ola1":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Lorna1":["elizabethn","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],"Lorna2":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],"Evie1":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],"Evie3":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"]}
mylist=[[k]+v for k,v in students.items()]
with open("mylist.csv", 'w', newline='') as myfile:
     wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     wr.writerows(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

To write to CSV (without importing any libraries)

```
students = {
    "Ola":["elizabethy","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],
    "Evie":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"],
    "Lorna":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],
    "Morgan":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],
    "Ola1":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],
    "Lorna1":["elizabethn","beale/cambray","st_hildas"],
    "Lorna2":["beale/cambray","elizabethn","st_hildas"],
    "Evie1":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethy"],
    "Evie3":["st_hildas","beale/cambray","elizabethn"]}

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in students.keys():
        f.write("%s, %s\n"%(key,','.join(students[key])))
```

To read the CSV back into a dictionary:

```
students1 = dict()
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       key, value = line.strip().split(', ')
       students1[key] = value.split(',')
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh How would I read the csv file back into the dictionary in the same format it left?